# Windows form keeps popping up even when declared close

Tags: vb.net, authentication

I'm currently developing a generic document tracking system with a login form. I have used an Access 2013 database for my back end for storing the credentials. All works, seems fine, until this happens

[image: login form keeps popping out even when it is declared close]

The code:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Dim login = Me.UsersPasswordsTableAdapter.UsernamePasswordString(txtUsername.Text, txtPass.Text)

    If login Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Authentication Error! Please Try Again!", "MARINA XI" & vbCritical)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("User " & txtUsername.Text & " verified" & vbNewLine & "Welcome!", "MARINA XI", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        frm_CUSTOMER_INTERFACE.lblAdmin.Text = CStr(txtUsername.Text)
        frm_CUSTOMER_INTERFACE.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

There is are no errors or other malicious things detected, I don't know why this little login form keeps popping out when the above code says close.

oh, and by the way, i have a splash screen like this, timed for 8.5 seconds until the login form appears and closes this splash screen form

[Splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUu0o.png)

It's code is the ff:

```
Private Sub LoadOutClk_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadOutClk.Tick
    If LoadOutClk.Interval = 8500 Then
        Me.Hide()
        frm_ADMIN_LOGIN.Show()

    End If
End Sub
```

The code for the login form is posted above..

Comment: If the login window first closes then opens again, the issue with the code is not here. We need to see the code where loginForm.Show is called.

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing passwords in plain text in the DB?

Comment: sadly @JoelCoehoorn , i did